# How to add custom button action in list make by HelpList class in PrestaShop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello I'm developing new payment plugin for PrestaShop 1.6. I made functionality for listing all payment request made by my plugin via HelpList class. Is there a way for add custom button action and manipulation each of row in mu list? I search a solution with not successes.

Thanks for help! Cheers!

This is a my Admin  Controler class.

```
class AdminNameModuleController extends ModuleAdminController {

public function __construct()
{

    // Call of the parent constructor method
    parent::__construct();


    // Add actions
    //$this->addRowAction('view');
    //$this->addRowAction('delete');
    $this->addRowAction('test');
}

public function initToolbar()
{
    $this->toolbar_btn = array();
}

public function processTest()
{
    // Do your button processing here
}

public function displayTestLink($token = null, $id, $name = null)
{
    $tpl = $this->createTemplate('helpers/list/list_action_test.tpl');

    $tpl->assign(array(
        'href' => self::$currentIndex.'&token='.$this->token.'&
                     '.$this->identifier.'='.$id.'&test'.$this->table.'=1',
            'action' => $this->l('Test')
    ));

    return $tpl->fetch();
}


public function initProcess()
{

    parent::initProcess();

    if (Tools::getValue('test'.$this->table))
    {
        $this->display = 'test';
        $this->action = 'test';
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, when you are defining your fields list array (probably in constructor) you can also add action buttons like this.

```
$this->addRowAction('mybutton');
```

Then you need to set controller's action if your custom button is clicked.

```
public function initProcess()
{
    if (Tools::getIsset('mybutton'.$this->table))
    {
        $this->action = 'mybutton';
    }
    parent::initProcess();
}
```

And finally create a method which handles the action.

```
public function processMybutton()
{
    // Do your button processing here
}
```

**Edit**

You said you are using `HelperList` to generate a list but I don't see any usage of it.

[Here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/admin/AdminGroupsController.php#L32) is an example of how to generate a list. For a list you need to define two things: `table` and `fields_list` properties. If you wish to have actions, add them like in the example. Then a `renderList()` method will do the rest for you.

Comment: I will write class which extends AdminController, thats right? Becouse method `addRowAction` non PaymentCore method..

Comment: @htmlbrewery Yes you need an admin controller class which extends `ModuleAdminController`.

Comment: @TheDrot Thank You for all helping. I will try. :)

Comment: I'm tried everything -- declare classe which extends `ModuleAdminController` in this class I declare `processTest` and  `displayTestLink` methods but my custom action don't show in dropdown menu with View and Edit buttons. Any ideas why doesn't work? Where I am wrong ?

Comment: @htmlbrewery Edit your question and show us your controller code.

Comment: @TheDrot question updated! Again thanks for helping!

Comment: Thanks :) I added `table` and `fields_list`, but no result, I call HelpList functionality in `getContent` method at My payment module class thats is wrong ?

Comment: @htmlbrewery Let's continue this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134783/room-for-thedrot-and-htmlbrewery).